# Why can't I scan from control panel of Canon Pixma TS6220

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon

This is a new printer for me on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  After searching for ways to install, I added this printer via the  http://localhost:631/ website.  I have also installed “ScanGear MP Ver. 3.70 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)” from Canon’s driver support  website for this printer (https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/pixma-ts6220?tab=drivers_downloads), as well as scangearmp2 (version 3.70.3-1804+2).  I can scan with Simple Scan, Xsane, and $ scangearmp2 in terminal, but not by using the printer’s control panel, “scan to computer” or “attach to email”.  When I select this option, the display shows a response (“Processing – please wait momentarily”), but there is no response in the platen and the “process” ends and the display returns to its normal state.
Am I missing some drivers/files, or were the files that I downloaded put in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that particular model, but for all my Canon printers, that functionality has depended on having Windows software installed "MP Navigator EX".

I just tested this by starting my Windows 7 Virtual Machine which has the software installed. After that, when I pressed the "Scan" button on the printer control panel, a menu came up asking me where I wanted to scan to, USB or PC, and the name of the virtual machine was listed by "PC".  The scan completed normally and was placed into "My Documents" folder in my account on the virtual machine.

When I close the virtual machine and press the "Scan" button, I only get the choice of USB.

Bottom line, it's Windows only.

Comment: I use HP printers, and "Scan to Computer" from the printer menu does not work in them as well under Linux. I use **Simple Scan** .

Comment: Agreed, I use simple scan, Xsane, or the Canon scangearmp2. All work, but not the printer control panel.

Comment: Here is a post where a user says that they use Cannon MX532 printer scanning operated through the control panel: https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx3HBL3S8FJ6E4O/ref=ask_dp_lsw_al_hza?asin=B00HM0IV4S